# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-contract, truffle-migration

I've been struggling on this for days, and been googling a bunch of things but still no luck. Here's my code for `2_deploy_contracts.js`:

```
const CoinCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./CoinCrowdsale.sol")

module.exports = function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  return liveDeploy(deployer, accounts);
};

const duration = {
  seconds: function(val) { return val},
  minutes: function(val) { return val * this.seconds(60) },
  hours:   function(val) { return val * this.minutes(60) },
  days:    function(val) { return val * this.hours(24) },
  weeks:   function(val) { return val * this.days(7) },
  years:   function(val) { return val * this.days(365)}
};

function latestTime() {
  return web3.eth.getBlock('latest').timestamp;
}

async function liveDeploy(deployer, accounts) {
  const startTime = latestTime() + duration.seconds(1); // one second in the future
  const endTime = startTime + (86400 * 30); // 30 days
  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000);
  const wallet = accounts[0];

  return deployer.deploy(CoinCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet);
}
```

and here's the error message:

```
➜  COIN git:(master) ✗ truffle deploy --network ropsten --reset
Using network 'ropsten'.

Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js
  Replacing Migrations...
  ... 0x64f00774e5e7322d4a3d44dc0a1ef15962dc898750c7adbb2ebc3fe39872ee39
  Migrations: 0x10c30744d4860f3ca714d52b07e7c864d32f5e01
Saving successful migration to network...
  ... 0x12637ca8c8dc5dde86831594b4b1084dad776d080523b2551a0e142d9bd5bdf7
Saving artifacts...
Running migration: 2_deploy_contracts.js
Saving successful migration to network...
(node:81173) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Web3ProviderEngine does not support synchronous requests.
    at ProviderError.ExtendableError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-error/index.js:10:1)
    at new ProviderError (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/error.js:17:1)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:71:1
    at WalletProvider.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-provider/wrapper.js:109:1)
    at Object.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-migrate/index.js:209:1)
    at RequestManager.send (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:58:1)
    at Eth.send [as getBlock] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/web3/lib/web3/method.js:145:1)
    at latestTime (/Users/glaksmono/Documents/COIN/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js:17:19)
    at liveDeploy (/Users/glaksmono/Documents/COIN/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js:21:21)
    at module.exports (/Users/glaksmono/Documents/COIN/migrations/2_deploy_contracts.js:4:10)
(node:81173) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:81173) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
  ... 0x1688c2faeb17b37432f524d18e125675234b5b68abde005b7245980e7c6d8f2a
Saving artifacts...
➜  COIN git:(master) ✗ truffle version
Truffle v4.0.6 (core: 4.0.6)
Solidity v0.4.19 (solc-js)
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
const CoinCrowdsale = artifacts.require("./CoinCrowdsale.sol")

module.exports = async function(deployer, network, accounts) {
  return await liveDeploy(deployer, accounts);
};

const duration = {
  seconds: function(val) { return val},
  minutes: function(val) { return val * this.seconds(60) },
  hours:   function(val) { return val * this.minutes(60) },
  days:    function(val) { return val * this.hours(24) },
  weeks:   function(val) { return val * this.days(7) },
  years:   function(val) { return val * this.days(365)}
};

async function latestTime() {
  const latestBlock = await web3.eth.getBlock('latest');
  return latestBlock.timestamp;
}

async function liveDeploy(deployer, accounts) {
  const startTime = latestTime() + duration.seconds(1); // one second in the future
  const endTime = startTime + (86400 * 30); // 30 days
  const rate = new web3.BigNumber(1000);
  const wallet = accounts[0];

  return deployer.deploy(CoinCrowdsale, startTime, endTime, rate, wallet);
}
```

The modifications are `await`ing for the promises to actually finish.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me: https://gist.github.com/glaksmono/88e4c769f0cbfd94ddf973c5b2460bb4